# Continuous extension of $f(x,y)=\left(\frac{1+y+x^2}{y}\right)^y$

Tags: limits, analysis, functions, continuity

The function $f(x,y)=\left(\frac{1+y+x^2}{y}\right)^y$ is not defined for $y=0$, so to extend $f$ continuously I want to define $f(x,0)$ as :
$$f(x,0)=\lim _{y \rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{1+y+x^2}{y}\right)^y$$
This limit seems to be equal to $1$, but my textbook says that "the function is continuously extendible in $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y=0\}$ with the value $e^{1+x^2}$".

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Could it possibly be an error with the book? That limit does approach that value if $y\rightarrow\infty$ but I don't see where $e$ appears as you go to $0$

Comment: The function is not defined everywhere when $y<0.$ Specifically, when $y<0$ and $1+x^2+y\geq 0.$ So you have to determine what you mean by the limit. You might want to restrict $y\to0^+.$

Comment: The limit is indeed $1$. Perhaps a mistake in your book?